# modify first entry of grouped data based on subsequent entries

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the dataset below:

```
df <- structure(list(test = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"),
                 id = c("PID1", "PID1", "PID1", "PID2", "PID2", "PID2", "PID3", "PID3", "PID3"),
                 date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-18"),
                 status_1 = c("Symp", "Symp", "uninfected", "Asymp", "Symp", "uninfected", "Asymp", "Asymp", "uninfected"),
                 status_2 = c("Symp", "Symp", "uninfected", "pre-Symp", "Symp", "uninfected", "Asymp", "Asymp", "uninfected")),
            class = "data.frame",
            row.names = c(NA, -9L)
            )
```

I'd like to identify individuals whose `status_1` is `Asymp` at the first `test` and check whether within ***14 days*** they are `Symp`.

Such individuals should have their `status_2` change to `pre-Symp`, otherwise, their status should remain the same such e.g. individual with id `PID3`.

- This individual is `Asymp` after the first test and does not transition to `Symp` within 14 days so his status remains `Asymp`

Here's the code I tried to put together but I keep running into errors:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(status_2 = case_when(test == "1st" & 
                                status_1 == "Asymp" & 
                                status_1[date + 14] != "Symp" ~ "pre-Symp",
                              TRUE ~ status_1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom function which checks for the status within that time interval.

```
library(dplyr)

check_status <- function(x, date) {
  if(first(x) == 'Asymp' & any(x == 'Symp')) {
    if (date[which.max(x == 'Symp')] - first(date) < 14)
      x[1] <- 'pre-Symp'
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Now apply this function by group :

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(status_2 = check_status(status_1, date))

# test  id    date       status_1   status_2  
#  <chr> <chr> <date>     <chr>      <chr>     
#1 1st   PID1  2020-01-01 Symp       Symp      
#2 2nd   PID1  2020-01-13 Symp       Symp      
#3 3rd   PID1  2020-01-17 uninfected uninfected
#4 1st   PID2  2020-01-01 Asymp      pre-Symp  
#5 2nd   PID2  2020-01-13 Symp       Symp      
#6 3rd   PID2  2020-01-20 uninfected uninfected
#7 1st   PID3  2020-01-01 Asymp      Asymp     
#8 2nd   PID3  2020-01-14 Asymp      Asymp     
#9 3rd   PID3  2020-01-18 uninfected uninfected
```